# Error in response to "import arcpy" - RuntimeError: NotInitialized

Tags: arcpy, installation, pyscripter

I am setting up a new computer and installed ArcGIS 10.4 with Python 2.7.10. I then downloaded PyScripter to use as an editor. When I try import arcpy, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 608, in <module>
    env = GPEnvironments(gp)
   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 605, in GPEnvironments
    return GPEnvironment(geoprocessor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 561, in __init__
    self._refresh()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 563, in _refresh
    envset = (set(env for env in self._gp.listEnvironments()))
RuntimeError: NotInitialized
```

I ensured that Python and PyScripter are both running 32 bit versions, ensured the paths were correct in PyScripter, tried setting the PYTHONPATH under the system environment settings, and I have tried suggestions found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6279/avoiding-import-arcpy-error-runtimeerror-notinitialized-when-using-idle) but continue to get the same error. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I use a batch file, which i stored inside the folder where pyscripter.exe is. May you have to check and correct pathes for your arcgis installation (e.g. 10.3 -> 10.4).

```
@echo off
SET PYSC_DIR=%~dp0

SET ESRI_Version=ArcGIS10.3
SET ESRI_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3
SET PYTHONDIR=C:\Python27\%ESRI_Version%

SET PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONDIR%
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYSC_DIR%\Lib\rpyc.zip;%PYTHONPATH%

PATH=%PATH%;%PYSC_DIR%;%PYSC_DIR%\Lib;%PYTHONDIR%;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\EsriProductionMapping\Desktop10.3\Bin

start "PyScripter" "%PYSC_DIR%\PyScripter.exe" --python27
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was not connected to network directly or thru VPN to validate ArcGIS License. Once I connected to network, the error "RuntimeError: NotInitialized" was resolved and my script ran successfully.